# Eclipse não atualiza mudanças nas classes

Tags: java, eclipse

Sou iniciante em Java e no uso da IDE Eclipse, Estava funcionando normalmente, quando as mudanças que eu fiz nas classes pararam de aparecer no console. 
Por exemplo: se anteriormente o programa estava escrito assim:

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("olá mundo");
    }
}
```

O console imprimia olá mundo normalmente, mas quando eu fiz uma alteração na classe e deixei como abaixo:

```
public class Programa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("olá mundo");
        System.out.println("nao está funcionando");
    }
}
```

Ao executar o código, o console continua mostrando apenas olá mundo, mesmo que eu clique em salvar. É como se eu não tivesse feito nenhuma alteração na classe.

Além disso, quando crio uma nova classe, ao rodar o programa, mesmo que o código não tenha nenhum problema sintático, o eclipse não roda nada, apenas diz que não consegui encontrar ou carregar a classe principal com a mensagem:  **could not find or load main class no console**

Comment: Verifique as variáveis de ambiente de seu eclipse, verifique o qual java está sendo utilizado por seu projeto. seu código está ok: https://repl.it/@andremartds/BiodegradableBuoyantOrders

Comment: Por acaso você desabilitou o `Project` > `Build automatically`?

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada em sua run configurations:

Menu Run -> Run Configurations -> Java Applocation -> suaclass

Veja se a Main Class está definida corretamente

Answer (score 0):

crie novamente a classe marcando a caixa public static void main(String[] args) [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]